# Controlling Fan speed

Tags: fancontrol

I recently installed Ubuntu on to a HP Presario CQ60 The fan works but at a constant slow speed. I have tried installing fancontrol but with no success
process came up with this message

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

Comment: Uninstall fancontrol. Do you know what your CPU temps are? Maybe there's no need to spin the fans faster if there isn't any heat issue. You can install the `lm-sensors` and `indicator-sensors` programs to see/monitor these temps.

Comment: I have removed fancontrol I have no idea of the temps. The laptop does shut down sometimes  and will allow restart after it has cooled down for 10 min

Comment: Did you install the software that I mentioned?